# Is there a way I can affect one page in my project by the events that happen in another page

Tags: javascript, dom, search

for a project I am looking on testing the fastest and most efficient way to obtain search results where the output of those results are always on a 'results.html' page. So in hindsight when the search button is clicked in the search page the event that I give it in my javascript file and the results will show up in my 'results.html' page. In this specific project, I will have 'Chemistry, Algebra, History, and Art' as the results that show up when I type in the input tag.

```
  <datalist id="option">
    <option value = "Chemistry"></option>
    <option value = "Algebra"></option>
    <option value = "History"></option>
    <option value = "Art"></option>
  </datalist>
```

Once one of those options is chosen I can redirect to a div where all those information is pertaining. and Hide the rest of the information that was not asked for.

I just do not know how to affect one page from another page with javascript.

Thank you for any help or ideas would be grateful.

Comment: When you say "affect one page from another page with javascript" you mean pages in two different tabs? or are you using any Single Page Application frameworks such as angular, react? What do you mean by page?

Comment: @Ramesh I am not using any single Page application Framework I am only using pure js. I mean once the input bar has been filled with one of the subject and the event is happening once the button is clicked then you are able to affect another separate HTML page.

Comment: I assume no server side calls as well?

Comment: @Ramesh I would like to use server side call like node.js but I am not sure how to implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store data across multiple requests/pages, there has to be some kind of state management. I would tend to classify them as Server side state management or client side state management.

For client side the below options can be used. Please remember as a developer we cannot take client side storage for granted as user might have disabled it or can manipulate the data. Each of this come with size restrictions as well.

1. Use of localStorage (Data is persisted across browser restarts) /
    sessionStorage (data is persisted across user session only)
2. Use of cookies
3. If it is a single page app, you can store the data in DOM or
   application variable or data store.

If state management has to be done with server side you may consider. These are framework agnostic and each framework or stack provides their own implementation to do the same.

1. Query Strings
2. Hidden Fields in the page
3. Session Store

Hope this gives you a pointer to what to look next.